# Shifting and joining two tables

Tags: list-manipulation, join

I have the two following tables that I would like to join across the second dimension. Both tables run from -1.2 to +1.2 across the second dimension. Hence, the resultant table should run from -1.2 to 3.6. Here's the sample tables:

```
P = Table[{i^2, j}, {i, 10}, {j, -1.2, 1.2, .2}]
S = Table[{i^2, j}, {i, 10}, {j, -1.2, 1.2, .2}];
```

I know I have to use shift and map functions somehow. Just cannot figure it out. Thanks in advance

Comment: Should the result be `R=Table[{i^2,j},{i,10},{j,-1.2,3.8,.2}]`? Maybe `ArrayFlatten[{{P, MapAt[# + 2.6 &, S, {All, All, 2}]}}]` is what you are looking for?

Comment: It works. Thanks a ton